# Java 1.6.x ant build slower on OSX?

Tags: java, macos, ant

At my wits end here. We've recently grabbed a Mac Pro to test out as a development environment, moving from Ubuntu - we were really hoping to see some serious decrease of our build times, but in fact the opposite is true. I'm wondering if we're missing something config related with Mavericks, we've already disabled spotlight on the appropriate directories.. messed around with ANT options giving up to 8G of memory for the builds.

Is HFS+ that much slower that EXT3? The build is writing 55k+ files to an exploded ear.

I've run disk tests on the mac, and we're seeing close to 1GB/s read time & 750MB/s write time so it doesn't seem to be hardware related. The linux build completes in just under 8 minutes, whereas the Mac Pro is looking at 9.5 minutes.

I'd like to avoid any kind of religious style OS discussions, I also know we could try installing Linux on the mac and see what happens, but at that point I'm not sure we're seeing a reason to spend $1600 more than our current high end non-Apple build. Looking more for any 'obvious' reasons we might be seeing this issue.

Thanks.

---

Answering my own question - unfortunately we sent the machine back, but later when moving to macbook pros, we discovered that we were still using a pretty old version of ANT (1.7.x), and the weblogic deps also had ant 1.7.x in the class path. We moved to 1.9.x & saw a big increase in speed on the macbook pros, so I suspect that a newer version of any may have seen some speed increase on the Mac Pro as well.

Comment: `I'd like to avoid any kind of religious style OS discussions` Are the `.java` files edited in vim or emacs?

Answer (score 1):

You've run some disk tests on the mac - how about on the Linux box?  It's possible it's faster than the mac in that regard.  Something else to check out - is the mac using filevault?  I've noticed that will really eat into compile times vs raw disk, but it doesn't usually show up on a disk read / write test that's using a single large block of data.

Comment: I'll check which drive is the linux build, unfortunately the machine on my desk is more out of date than that one. My builds are in the 10 minute range, so the Mac is (barely) faster than my machine. Pretty sure the SSD in the higher end Linux box is pretty similar to what's in the Mac. We've disabled filevault on it.

Comment: So, the Mac is way way faster pure IO wise. It's using essentially a flash drive. Reads and writes are as above. It's a SATA SSD in the linux machine, which maxes out at 600MB/s either way..